# Simple if statement not working in wordpress echo is working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am hoping that someone can help me, I am writing a simple if statement inside WordPress but for some reason it does not seem to execute the way I want it to work.

```
    $g_map = get_the_id().(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_et_business_g_pagetype', true));
if ('map' == $g_map) {
    echo "<h1>This is the map page</h1>".$g_map;
    }
```

The if statement is to execute when a Custom Post Meta Field = map

If I execute this line `echo get_the_id().(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_et_business_g_pagetype', true));` outside the if statement is does show that the value is `"map"`

So "map should equal map" and the echo should run as intended, but I cannot understand why it is not...

Any ideas why this maybe happening and how I can fix it will be appreciated.

Comment: Whilst it wont answer your question and is more a style comment it is usual to ask `if ($variable == value)` than `if (value == $variable)` Technically they are both the same just most people are used to reading it the other way round.

Comment: get_the_id() returns an int, so I am not sure how an int concatenated with anything = "map"

Comment: Thanks for the input... If I do echo get_the_id().(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_et_business_g_pagetype', true)); then I get the value as map... just not inside the if statement... Thanks Anigel, I usually write it the same way, I rewrote it to see if it will make a difference with the map as a set value... The lol lol lol you actually just solved it for me... but I will keep this comment here :-)

Comment: I have placed the get_the_id() to see if I have the right post! - so infact map did not equal map... it was map = (postnumber)map and this is why the if statement did not work! - Thanks a million for pointing me in the right direction! It is now solved!

Comment: No problem, we have all done something similar.

Comment: how do I mark your answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have placed the get_the_id() to see if I have the right post! - so infact map did not equal map... it was map = (postnumber)map and this is why the if statement did not work! - Thanks a million for pointing me in the right direction! It is now solved!

Answer (score 0):

Do a var_dump($_map); and see what returns it might be a case issue or is doesn't return map. oh and if you want to refactor it to be a little better use === then it won't type cast it but meh it is a string so not much difference.

Comment: that´s supposed to be a comment.